# nginx proxy multiurl WordPress keep redirecting

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm currently trying to setup an WordPress behind a nginx proxy configured as follow:

```
server {

 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name  localhost;
 #charset koi8-r;
 #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

 location / {
  client_max_body_size 200M;

  proxy_redirect              off;
  proxy_read_timeout          1m;
  proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
  proxy_pass http://a2a4d2d0a77264312bfd46b264cba9c8f-wordpress/;

  sub_filter_once off;
  sub_filter_types *;
  sub_filter_last_modified off;
  sub_filter '<domain-1>' '$host';
  sub_filter '<domain-2>' '$host';
 }
}
```

This  proxy is configured to serve two domain  and 
 is password protected (http_auth) and  is not (domain-1 is an external uri and domain-2 is internal)
In order to do so I sub_filter the uri called to allow internal to call resource without using http_auth
but WordPress keeps redirecting me (301) to the domain-1 which is the one set as website_URL and homepage inside WordPress config

How to avoid this? How to make WordPress serve two different domains without redirecting the user?

curl https:/// -vv :

```
*   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443...
* Connected to <domain-2> (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=<domain-2>
*  start date: Jan  4 16:50:48 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Apr  4 16:50:47 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "<domain-2>" matched cert's "<domain-2>"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55ff559cca60)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: <domain-2>
> user-agent: curl/7.74.0
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 250)!
< HTTP/2 301
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Wed, 12 Jan 2022 13:07:09 GMT
< location: https://<domain-1>/
< server: Unknow
< x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.27
< x-redirect-by: WordPress
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host <domain-2> left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;` was the issue since passing the host to wordpress would induce a redirect;

Just removing the line did the job

current configuration:

```
server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name  localhost;

      #charset koi8-r;
      #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

      location / {
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_buffering             off;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://<id>-wordpress;
        
        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types *;
        sub_filter_last_modified off;
        sub_filter '<domain-1>' '$host';
        sub_filter '<domain-2>' '$host';
      }
    }
```